# requiring file inside request

Tags: node.js, require, multilingual

I am playing around with Node.js and I was wondering if what I'm doing can be considered best practice or not, I still got a lot of stuff to learn.

I am trying to implement a multi-language layout, by creating more JSON files that are then loaded depending on the http header (language). What I am doing is this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
try {
    var words = require('../languages/' + req.headers["accept-language"].substr(0, 2).toLowerCase());
} catch(err) {
    console.log("no language found - falling back to english");
    var words = require('../languages/en');
}

res.render('index', { language: words });
};
```

now, I am pretty sure there's something wrong there. as I think requiring should be done once only, and I am requiring it with each request. But, I can't think of any other way since I need to access the language in the request header.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, Node will give you the already-loaded module on subsequent `require` invocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requiring two different files. So am not sure why you think you a repeating yourself.

Eventually you should turn you language file into a actual module that's located in a local node_modules folder or in the same node_modules your app uses.

This way you can require you language module like this.

```
var language = require('language');
```

Inside you language module there should be a index file and lib directory.

**index.js**

```
exports.en= require('./lib/en'),
exports.fr= require('./lib/fr'),
exports.de= require('./lib/de'),
```

Then you will be able to use your module like this.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

  language = require('language');

try {

    var words = language[req.headers["accept-language"].substr(0, 2).toLowerCase()]();
} catch(err) {
    console.log("no language found - falling back to english");
    var words = language.en();
}

res.render('index', { language: words });
};
```

REPLACE above with this.

```
exports.index = function(req, res){

    var language = require('language');
        supported_languages = ['en', 'fr' , 'de'],
        accept_language = req.headers["accept-language"].substr(0, 2).toLowerCase();

    if(supported_languages.indexOf(accept_language) !== -1){

        var words = language[accept_language]();

    }else {
        console.log("no language found - falling back to english");
        var words = language.en();
    }

    res.render('index', { language: words });    
};
```

Comment: looks amazing! I am getting an error, tho. at the line inside the try; i am getting: `[TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined]`

Comment: That just means the headers are not present in req object. Try console.log req.headers and see if its empty.

Comment: I am getting them... `console.log(req.headers["accept-language"].substr(0, 2).toLowerCase());` returns me `it`, that is my language

Comment: It looks like you have a typo there is extra ) at the end of var words = language.req.headers["accept-language"].substr(0, 2).toLowerCase());

Comment: yea, I had that before, I removed it before telling your about this error, it's not because of the `)`. With that character, it wouldn't compile at all

Comment: it's a too good answer not to work... you must have missed something really small which I can't see either. it looks like it's trying to access `language`'s req, that's why it return undefined.

Comment: `TypeError: Property 'it' of object #<Object> is not a function` - getting there tho!

Comment: the problem with this is if I am loading a language that is not exported in index.js in languages - the error will be `Cannot read property 'welcome' of undefined` how can I make load english if no language is set? the try catch becomes useless with your method

Comment: Completely removed the try/catch replace with simple if and else that checks the accept-header against supported languages array. If language is is not supported it will default to english as you you wanted.

Comment: If you mean, the supported languages array. You could abstract that out as-well. In your index file you would have exports.supported= ['en', 'fr', 'de'];  Remove if from you request files and then change supported_languages to language.supported();

Comment: ok, works good now! although you need to remove some `()` from your code!

Comment: Yep just noticed that as-well its no longer a function so doesn't need the parentheses.

Comment: also, do you reckon there's a way to have this if statement inside the languages module? if you can help me, i'd be very very grateful, really! - like by passing the header language, and having returned the exports.headerlanguage, or something among these lines.

Answer (score 1):

For internationalization, I would highly recommend i18n.

[i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node)

Comment: yea, I heard of it but, as I am still learning, I guess it's important to code as much as possible to learn more instead of having to just install the modules. Thanks anyway, I am sure I will use it in the future!